# JXLS ignores template style, how can I force it to keep the column widths as they are in the template file?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jxls

I am using JXLS to generate an excel file using a custom template. The template is simply the standard grid export template that comes with the library, except I have changed the width of some of the columns in the template file. My code is mostly just a copy of the sample code.

```
 private void exportAsXLS(List<CalExportItem> exportItems, OutputStream os1) {

    try (InputStream is = CalDataExporter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(TEMPLATE_FILEPATH)) {
        xlsExporter.registerGridTemplate(is);
        xlsExporter.gridExport(Arrays.asList(HEADERS), exportItems, FIELDS, os1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception exporting as XLS", e);
    }
}
```

I have basically just copied the "SimpleExporter" sample

```
public class CalXlsExportHelper {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CalXlsExportHelper.class);

private byte[] templateBytes;

public void registerGridTemplate(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[4096];
    int count;
    while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
        os.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    templateBytes = os.toByteArray();
}

public void gridExport(Iterable headers, Iterable dataObjects, String objectProps, OutputStream outputStream) {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(templateBytes);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(is, outputStream);

    //******** key difference with SimpleExporter ********
    // Passing false to areaBuilder in order to prevent clearing of cells and loss of template style
    AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer, false);

    List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
    Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
    Context context = new Context();
    context.putVar("headers", headers);
    context.putVar("data", dataObjects);
    GridCommand gridCommand = (GridCommand) xlsArea.getCommandDataList().get(0).getCommand();
    gridCommand.setProps(objectProps);
    xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Sheet1!A1"), context);
    try {
        transformer.write();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to write to output stream", e);
        throw new JxlsException("Failed to write to output stream", e);
    }
}
```

}

And this is what I have in the template file:

```
Author:
jx:area(lastCell="A3")

jx:grid(lastCell="A3" headers="headers" data="data" areas=[A2:A2, A3:A3]  
   formatCells="String:A3,Integer:B3,Long:B3,Short:B3,Double:B3,Float:B3,BigDecimal:B3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SimpleExporter there is no option to configure this because you cannot modify [Context](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/javadoc/jxls/org/jxls/common/Context.html) and [Transformer](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/javadoc/jxls/org/jxls/transform/Transformer.html) objects used during export.

But if you use other ways to export you will have the following options

1. Use [Transformer](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/javadoc/jxls/org/jxls/transform/AbstractTransformer.html) `setIgnoreColumnProps` and `setIgnoreRowProps` methods to ignore column/row widths for example

   ```
   ((PoiTransformer)transformer).setIgnoreColumnProps(true);
   ((PoiTransformer)transformer).setIgnoreRowProps(true);
   ```
2. Use [Context.Config](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/javadoc/jxls/org/jxls/common/Context.Config.html) to set ignoring of all source cell styles
   `context.getConfig().setIgnoreSourceCellStyle(true)`

Comment: this isn't working for me I have used context.config